# Trying to get my play button to work harmoniously with my pause button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been developing a C# music player for months now and haven't been using the built in playlist commands, and it's too late for me to go back and do that now. I use this code for my play button right now (we use a openfiledialog to load music into a listbox):

```
private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WMPPlayer.URL = paths[filelist.SelectedIndex];
    }
```

and here is my pause code:

```
private void Pause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.pause();
    }
```

There is no timer or progress bar to tell if it's pausing but it does make the music stop so it seems to be working. However, when I click play after that it starts the song over. I'm not sure how to save the index of the song without a timer, and then make the play button check to see where the song is paused at. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the current position of the audio using

```
double pausedPosition = WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition
```

In your current implementation you're setting the URL in the play button. I believe this works because the default behavior is for it to start playing as soon as its URL is set (`WMPPlayer.settings.autoStart`). To get more control, you could disable it and change your code in the Play button into:

```
WMPPlayer.URL = paths[filelist.SelectedIndex];
WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = pausedPosition;
WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

Comment: Where would i put that line?                                                               
double pausedPosition = WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition

Comment: you would put it in the same method that you pause it. Make sure you don't load the pausedPosition if they are loading a new audio file. Check to see if the current URL is the same as the new one being loaded, and set the pausedPosition only then.